# Failed to connect to master, spark in docker

Tags: apache-spark, docker

I am running spark on following docker image:

https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark

I am trying to run the spark-bench ( https://github.com/SparkTC/spark-bench ) I tried following command:

```
<SparkBench_Root>/KMean/bin/gen_data.sh
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@172.17.0.3:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@172.17.0.3:7077]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /172.17.0.3:7077]
16/03/16 08:00:36 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 172.17.0.3:7077
akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://sparkMaster@172.17.0.3:7077/), Path(/user/Master)]
at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala
```

Thanks
Shuja